# Changing text inside link element

Tags: javascript

After 3 clicks I want to change the link text to say done instead of next. I thought it was with innerHTML, but I could not get it to change.

Thank You

fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2w4YJ/2/

```
     var clicks = 0;
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName('buttonred');
        var link = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        button.onclick = function(e){

            if(clicks === 0){
                clicks ++;
                loadStudent();
                console.log("1");
            }else if(clicks === 1){
                clicks++;
                loadStudent2();
                console.log("2");
            }else if(clicks === 2){
                clicks ++;
                loadStudent3();

                console.log('3');
            }else{
                console.log(link);
                button.disabled = true;


                link.innerHTML = "done!";
                //button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                console.log(button);
            }
```

Comment: Give the link an ID and select it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName`, as its pluralised name suggests, returns a list of elements. So you're retrieving an array of elements that match the anchor tag.

For a quick and dirty fix, change your offending line of code to:

```
link[0].innerHTML = "done!"
```

This should produce this behaviour in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2w4YJ/4/).

However, you can't always predict that the anchor tag you want will be the first element in that array. So it may be better to give the anchor an ID and to use JavaScript's `getElementById` method to refer to it thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` which returns a node list and nodeList does not have an `innerHTML` property since it is the object that holds the collection of `anchors`. You need to fetch the DOM element from the node list so in this case you should do `link[0].innerHTML = "done!";` which will fetch the first anchor in the list (which happens to be the only one in this case, however you would need to use this based on the appropriate on). Alternatively you could provide an `id` to your anchor and use `document.getElementById('nextLinkId').innerHTML= "Done!"`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2MKyj/)**